# Getting error ImageView cannot be cast to LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop, drag

I am using Drag and drop functionality in my app. Everything is working fine but getting this error `ImageView cannot be cast to LinearLayout`.
And when i am directly trying to set image on the image view as I mentioned in comment part of my code then also i am getting blank on imageview screen.

Here is my code,

```
img1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) 
        {
            if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
            {
                status=1;
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("foo","bar");
                DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new DragShadowBuilder(v);
                v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
                return true;

            } 
            else 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });


    iv1.setOnDragListener(DragAndDropGameActivity.this);

}

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Drawable image=null;
     Drawable normalborder = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border);
     Drawable greenborder = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenborder);
    if(status==1)
    {
        image = v.getBackground();
        if (event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked & Started" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            image = v.getBackground();
            //self.setBackgroundDrawable(redBorder);
        } 
        else if (event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED)
        {
            //insideOfMe = true;
            //border=v.getBackground();
            //v.setBackground(greenborder);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Entered" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
        else if (event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exited" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //insideOfMe = false;
        } 
        else if (event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dropped" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
            ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            owner.removeView(view);
            LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
            container.addView(view);

            //image = v.getBackground();
            //iv1.setBackground(image);

            //iv1.setBackgroundDrawable(image);


         } 
        else if (event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED)
        {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ended" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
          return true;    

    }

    return false;
}
```

This is my LogCat,

```
10-28 11:53:35.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3095): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 11:53:35.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3095): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
10-28 11:53:35.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at com.example.draganddropgame.DragAndDropGameActivity.onDrag(DragAndDropGameActivity.java:121)
10-28 11:53:35.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.view.View.dispatchDragEvent(View.java:16371)
10-28 11:53:35.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1237)
10-28 11:53:35.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1237)
10-28 11:53:35.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1237)
10-28 11:53:35.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1237)
10-28 11:53:35.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1237)
10-28 11:53:35.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleDragEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3838)
10-28 11:53:35.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.access$600(ViewRootImpl.java:95)
10-28 11:53:35.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2999)
10-28 11:53:35.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-28 11:53:35.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-28 11:53:35.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-28 11:53:35.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 11:53:35.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-28 11:53:35.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-28 11:53:35.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-28 11:53:35.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is how my Layout looks,

[image]

Please help me..

Thanks.

Comment: what is line 121. is it this  `LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v`?

Comment: `LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;` although `iv1` is an ImageView! (I bet)

Comment: @Sherif elKhatib: yeah iv1 is also an ImageView.

Comment: If your xml is correctly defined and you are not casting incorrectly just do a clean and build.

Comment: You are casting ImageView to LinearLayout which is wrong. that is why you get excpetion

Comment: I just want to set that drag shadow image on iv1(ImageView).

Comment: @Raghunandan: I have edited something in my post please see!

Answer (score 0):

try to retrieve your LinearLayout from your xml

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(your linear layout id);
```

or create new one, but you have to add some additional code

> example :

```
 // creating LinearLayout
        LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        // specifying vertical orientation
        linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        // creating LayoutParams  
        LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); 
        // set LinearLayout as a root element of the screen 
        setContentView(linLayout, linLayoutParam);
```